# Need to find lowest differences between first line of an array and the rest ones

Tags: algorithm, array-algorithms

Well, I've been given a number of pairs of elements `(s,h)`, where `s` sends an `h` element on the `s`-th row of a 2d array.It is not necessary that each line has the same amount of elements, only known that there cannot be more than N elements on a line.

What I want to do is to find the lowest biggest difference(!) between a certain element of the first line and the rest ones.

Thus, if I have 3 lines with `(101,92) (100,25,95,52,101) (93,108,0,65,200)` what I want to find is 3, because I have to choose 92 and I have 95-92=3 from first to second and 93-92=1 form first to third.

I have reached a point where it is certain that if I have `s` lines with `n(i)` elements each and `i=0..s`, then `n0<=n1<=...<=ns` so as to have a good average performance scenario when picking the best-fit from 1st line towards the others.

However, I cannot think of a way lower than O(n<sup>2</sup>) or even maybe O(n<sup>3</sup>) in some cases. Does anyone have a suggestion about a fairly improved way to do this?

Comment: why not 101-101 = 0 bet lines 1 and 2?

Comment: because what i need to do is find the best fit from the first line in comparison with all the others. i may have a zero difference between first and second line if i choose 101, but then first to third line gives me 7 for 108-101, which is bigger than 3 which i got in the example i've written. Thanks a lot for asking because this point might be a little blury for someone who views my question!

Answer (score 1):

Combine all lines into a single list, also keeping track of which element comes from where.

Sort this list.

Have a last-value variable for each line.

For each item in the sorted list, update the last-value variable of the applicable list. If not all lines have a last-value set yet, do nothing. If it's an element from the first list:

- Recalculate the biggest difference for *all* of the last-value variables. Store this difference.

If it's an element from any other list:

- If all values have previous not been set, calculate the biggest difference. Otherwise, if the difference between the first list's last-value and this element is bigger than the biggest difference, update the biggest difference with this difference. Store this difference.

The smallest difference is the desired value.

**Example:**

```
Lists: (101,92) (100,25,95,52,101) (93,108,0,65,200)

Sorted  0  25 52 65 92 93 95 100 101 101 108 200
Source  2  1  1  2  0  2  1  1   0   1   2   2

Last[0] -  -  -  -  92 92 92 92  101 101 101 101
Last[1] -  25 52 52 52 52 95 100 100 101 101 101
Last[2] 0  0  0  65 65 93 93 93  93  93  108 200

Diff    -  -  -  -  40 41 3  8   8   8   7   9
Best    -  -  -  -  40 40 3  3   3   3   3   3
```

Best = 3 as required. Storing the actual items or finding them afterwards should be easy enough.

**Complexity:**

Let `n` be the total number of items and `k` be the number of lists.

`O(n log n)` for the combine + sort.

`O(nk)` (worst case) for the scan through, since we're checking `n` items and, at each item, we do maximum `O(k)` work.

So `O(n log n + nk)`.